# replacing 1 column with another based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to replace the values in column 1 of sheet 2(which is same as col 2 of sheet 1) by the corresponding values of column 1 of sheet 1.

```
SHEET 1             SHEET 2         RESULT SET  
    Col 1   Col 2           Col 1           Col 1
Row 1   A   1       Row 1   1       Row 1   A
Row 2   B   2       Row 2   2       Row 2   B
Row 3   C   3       Row 3   3       Row 3   C
Row 4   D   4       Row 4   4       Row 4   D
Row 5   E   5       Row 5   5       Row 5   E
```

Hope my question is not absurd
Thanks in Advance``

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to do?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but can't you just use a simple vlookup for this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the macrorecorder and then tweaked the code a little bit. This will adapt if you ever have a different number of rows. Hope this helps! Let me know if it's not quite what you meant.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim Count As Double

Count = 1

While Range("A" & CStr(Count)) <> ""
    Count = Count + 1
Wend

Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & CStr(Count - 1)).Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```